# Find position of elements of a dataframe inside other dataframe with R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following dataframe (DF_A):

```
PARTY_ID PROBS_3001 PROBS_3002 PROBS_3003 PROBS_3004 PROBS_3005 PROBS_3006 PROBS_3007 PROBS_3008
1:  1000000       0.03       0.58       0.01       0.42       0.69       0.98       0.55       0.96
2:  1000001       0.80       0.37       0.10       0.95       0.77       0.69       0.23       0.07
3:  1000002       0.25       0.73       0.79       0.83       0.24       0.82       0.81       0.01
4:  1000003       0.10       0.96       0.53       0.59       0.96       0.10       0.98       0.76
5:  1000004       0.36       0.87       0.76       0.03       0.95       0.40       0.53       0.89
6:  1000005       0.15       0.78       0.24       0.21       0.03       0.87       0.67       0.64
```

And I have this other dataframe (DF_B):

```
    V1   V2   V3   V4 PARTY_ID
1 0.58 0.69 0.96 0.98  1000000
2 0.69 0.77 0.80 0.95  1000001
3 0.79 0.81 0.82 0.83  1000002
4 0.76 0.96 0.96 0.98  1000003
5 0.76 0.87 0.89 0.95  1000004
6 0.64 0.67 0.78 0.87  1000005
```

I need to find the position of the elements of the DF_A in the DF_B to have something like this:

```
  PARTY_ID P1 P2 P3 P4
1 1000000 3 6 9 7
...
```

Currently I'm working with match function but it takes a lot of time (I have 400K rows). I'm doing this:

```
i <- 1
while(i < nrow(DF_A)){
  position <- match(DF_B[i,],DF_A[i,])
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Although it works, it's very slow and I know that it's not the best answer to my problem. Can anyone help me please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge and then `Map` with a by group operation:

```
df_a2 <- df_a[setDT(df_b), on = "PARTY_ID"]
df_a3 <- df_a2[, c(PARTY_ID,
                Map(f = function(x,y) which(x==y), 
                  x = list(.SD[,names(df_a), with = FALSE]),
                  y = .SD[, paste0("V",1:4), with = FALSE])), by = 1:nrow(df_a2)]

setnames(df_a3, paste0("V",1:5), c("PARTY_ID", paste0("P", 1:4)))[,nrow:=NULL]
df_a3
#  PARTY_ID P1 P2 P3 P4
#1:  1000000  3  6  9  7
#2:  1000001  7  6  2  5
#3:  1000002  4  8  7  5
#4:  1000003  9  3  3  8
#5:  1000003  9  6  6  8
#6:  1000004  4  3  9  6
#7:  1000005  9  8  3  7
```

Comment: @ValeriaLobosOssandón happy it helped! Just updated with some post-processing cleaning

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on 1 milion rows with two columns. It takes 14 ms on my computer.

```
# create data tables with matching ids but on different positions

x <- as.data.table(data.frame(id=sample(c(1:1000000), 1000000, replace=FALSE), y=sample(LETTERS, 1000000, replace=TRUE)))
y <- as.data.table(data.frame(id=sample(c(1:1000000), 1000000, replace=FALSE), z=sample(LETTERS, 1000000, replace=TRUE)))

# add column to both data tables which will store the position in x and y

x$x_row_nr <- 1:nrow(x)
y$y_row_nr <- 1:nrow(y)

# set key in both data frames using matching columns name
setkey(x, "id")
setkey(y, "id")

# merge data tables into one 
z <- merge(x,y)

    # now you just use this to extract what is the position
# of 100 hundreth record in x data table in y data table

z[x_row_nr==100, y_row_nr]
```

z will contain matching row records from both datasets with there columns attached.

Comment: Hi! I'm trying your solution with my data and I've already do that, but I get the two dataframes together. However, what I need is the position of the element inside the other. Can you please be more clear?

Comment: Sorry I edited my post. You can just extract the x_row_nr and y_row_nr, those are the matching positions. You can just delete all other columns in z besides x_row_nr and y_row_nr and here you are.

Comment: You can now use those two columns from z to quickly lookup for any given position.